# Committing external libraries to SVN?

Tags: svn, commit, subclipse

I'm using Subclipse 1.6 to work on a group project.  I have added some external JAR libraries to my build path and would like all my team members to be able to access them as well.  However, when I commit the chances, the team members all get error messages saying that they are missing the libraries.

I know of course that I could just send the JARs themselves over, but I'd like to make it so that the build paths are committed accordingly so they don't have to manually add the libraries.  Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you need a build tool that handles dependency management.

Hudson and Maven work well for this - consider this article

http://weblogs.java.net/blog/johnsmart/archive/2008/11/managing_automa.html

Comment: I second the notion. Even if you aren't using Maven, you can use Maven's dependency management capabilities to upload and download jar files. Setup Artifactory or Nexus as your local repository, so you can store the dependent libraries you built. If you use Ant, take a look at Ivy

Comment: Good point, David - In fact, I'm sure there's dozens of other alternatives to Maven, both free and commericial (if this is for work, you may be able to convince management to get a quality commercial tool, which typically comes with support.) I think exploring Maven is a good first step, and if it doesn't work fully, identify why and look for tools that fill the needs it doesn't.